# Manage route matching with a variable number of parameters

Tags: php, symfony

From a personal Symfony 5 project, I want to simulate a web file browser.(of directories located in server side)

My question is about routing, given possibles urls :

- localhost/directory-A/directory-A-1
- localhost/directory-A/directory-A-2
- localhost/directory-B/directory-B-1/directory-B-1-1
- localhost/directory-N/directory-C-1/directory-C-1-1/directory-C-1-1-1

As you can see, the arborescence may contain a variable number of hierarchical directories.
With the Symfony Router, How can I manage theses url with one controller ?

The content of the contoller should look like :

```
/**
 * @Route("???")
 */
public function browse(): Response
{
    // get all parameters (example : ['directory-B', 'directory-B-1', 'directory-B-1-1'])
    // From serverside, check in the filesystem if the path 'directory-B/directory-B-1/directory-B-1-1
    // If yes : return the list of files or directories contained in 'directory-B/directory-B-1/directory-B-1-1'
    // If no : return an error
}
```

My question is here : `@Route("???")` , how can I do what I want with Symfony routing ?

Question bonus : in directories, there will be only text files. With the routing system again, how can I create only one controller for all dynamic routes finishing by ".txt" ?

Examples of url :

- localhost/directory-A/directory-A-1/foo.txt
- localhost/directory-A/directory-A-2/faa.txt
- localhost/directory-B/directory-B-1/directory-B-1-1/fii.txt
- localhost/directory-N/directory-C-1/directory-C-1-1/directory-C-1-1-1/faa.txt

Comment: Have a route match on anything, and do the splitting inside your controller.

Comment: Just make sure you also give this controller a route prefix, so it doesn't accidentally match a route from a different controller.

Comment: @yivi maybe this is the best 'proper' solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have a route like [this](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/routing/slash_in_parameter.html):

```
share:
    path:       /browse/{path}
    controller: App\Controller\BrowserController::browse
    requirements:
        path: (.+)
```

Then in your controller simply split the incoming path to account for the directories, check their existence, etc:

```
public function browse(string $path): Response
{
    $pathParts = explode('/', $path);
    // do what you need here.

}
```

So you would end with things like:

```
| url path                 | partParts                                     |
|----------- --------------|-----------------------------------------------|
| /browse/foo              | ['foo']                                       |
| /browse/foo/bar          | ['foo', 'bar']                                |
| /browse/foo/bar/file.txt | ['foo', 'bar', 'file.txt']                    |
```

With the path parts you would be able to check for path existence, if it can be read, implement your own permission system, etc.